# Subscription system with Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm developing a restaurant catalog in which the restaurant owners pay a monthly fee for having their restaurant appear on the site. I was thinking in using Paypal recurring payments but I don't understand exactly how it works. Would Paypal automatically charge the fee each month? (Like auto-renew) or would the users be able to decide if they pay or not? I need that the users decide if they want to continue with the membership instead of being automatically charged. How can I achieve this with Paypal?

I'm using express checkout with instant payment notifications (IPN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurring Payments would be a subscription that would be charged automatically unless the profile was in a canceled or suspended state.  So if your customers signed up, they can indeed choose whether to pay or not if you give them a way to suspend their profile, which  you can do via the [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/) API.

If you would rather setup a way where users have to click a button to approve the payment each month then you could go with a billing agreement and a reference transaction.  In your SetExpressCheckout request you would make sure to include the billing agreement parameters to get a valid token, and then when the order is completed with that billing agreement you can use the transaction ID you get back from it in a [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) request in the future to process any amount using the previous billing info that PayPal has saved, so no additional login auth would be necessary.

Comment: another question... how do I specify notify_url with recurring payments?

Comment: To get IPN's from the recurring payments you'll need to setup IPN in your PayPal profile.

Comment: Is there a way to test it with sandbox?

Comment: Yes, the sandbox will send IPN's for recurring payments, but there's no way to really trigger them without waiting for the time to pass.  What you can do, though, is create an HTML form with your IPN URL set as the action, and then fill it with hidden fields matching what you expect to get from PayPal.  Then you can post it in a browser and see the result on screen, which helps with debugging.  Just keep in mind the data isn't coming from PayPal when you do that, so it won't verify against their server.